# Convert downloaded file to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, shapefile

It's my first time trying to convert this file to readable polygon in long lat. Here's the file source https://jakartasatu.jakarta.go.id/apijakasatu/data/public?id=3965b6c2-12c1-4b38-ae15-ea925fbdc5ba

The zip contains a lot of files. I tried to read the SHP only however error  comes out.
How do I read the zip data?

Currently my code is

```
!pip install geopandas
import geopandas

shp_file = geopandas.read_file('BANGUNAN CEMPAKA PUTIH.shp')
shp_file.to_file('myshpfile.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

Is this the right way? All I need is a table that shows the name, and polygon (in long lat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shapefile is in a projected coordinate reference system (CRS). To get a dataframe with the geometry in lon, lat coordinates, you need to [reproject](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) to a Geographic CRS, e.g. [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326).

```
import geopandas

dataframe = geopandas.read_file('BANGUNAN CEMPAKA PUTIH.shp').to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

Comment: I am getting this: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.

Comment: Works for me. Ensure you extract all the files from the zip, including the .prj file.

Comment: Hi I only get KECAMATAN,WILAYAH,geometry. Whereas column such as D_SUB_PENG, D_KEGIATAN is missing. Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: The shapefile (and thus the geodataframe) only contains two fields KECAMATAN and WILAYAH plus the geometry.